# What is the win-win word said in the film Arrival?

Tags: dialogue, arrival

In one of the visions, Louise's daughter asks her the definitive word to describe a win-win situation. What was the answer Louise told her daughter?

Answer (score 24):

The phrase provided was "**non-zero-sum game**".

A zero-sum game is when one "player" gains something at the expense of another "player" losing something. As such, a non-zero-sum game is when gains and losses can be made by all "players" without it affecting anyone else.

As such, this can be a "win-win" situation, where both "players" can gain something without anyone losing something.

Comment: It seems a better choice would have been "mutually beneficial" as I was also confused by their use of this negated term.

Comment: @RenaissanceProgrammer .... except that zero-sum game and non-zero-sum game are technical terms in the area of game theory - a branch of mathematics

Comment: @RenaissanceProgrammer her daughter demanded the science word for it.

Comment: @AnkitSharma https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mutualism_(biology)

Comment: Dr R Dizzle may or may not be just guessing, but he is unequivocally correct, as substantiated by the original Ted Chiang novella, "Story of Your Life" (pg 209 in the e-book collection, "Stories of Your Life and Others").  I believe the term for "definitively settled by the Author" in such contexts is "Word of God"?  This is thus Word of God for this question.